# PrimeFaces: Is there a way to put a hyperlink inside <p:message>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, hyperlink

After a user add an item to the cart successfully, I'd like to display a message like `Click here to continue shopping` and `Click here to view your cart` using `<p:message>` or `<p:growl>`.

I tried to google with keywords like PrimeFaces how to put hyperlink into `<p:message>` but nothing meaningful showed up. Hence, I'd be very grateful if you could share with me how to do this or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the following blog post : [FacesMessage Enhancements](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1894)

You can use `escape="false"`

```
<p:message escape="false" />

context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
    "Sample warn message", "PrimeFaces is developed by 
    <strong>Chuck Norris!</strong>"));
```

Or

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
    "Sample warn message", "Some Link
    <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/'>Visit W3Schools</a>"));
```

You could also take a look at this article by BalusC

[Using HTML in JSF messages](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-html-in-jsf-messages.html)

Comment: Be careful that you don't redisplay user-controlled input in `<p:messages escape="false">`.

Comment: @BalusC , changed it to `<p:message escape="false" />` according to the VDL `escape` supported in `<p:message` too